# How to distinguish between two forms connected to same Google SpreadSheet in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have two different forms. Each of them is connected to the same spreadsheet. I have also set up a **onFormSubmit(e)** trigger. Now my question is how can I distinguish between the form submissions based on the form. I have different logic for both the forms, so I need to get some identifier through which I can check which code to run?

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // something like this
  // if submission from FormA then do foo()
  // else if submission from FormB then do bar() 
}
```

Comment: Same Spreadsheet but different sheets - can't you just use for example `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1]` to get the sheet with each form's responses respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e.range.getSheet()` method will give you the sheet where the form response will be stored.

Use `sheet.getFormUrl()` to know the URL of the Google Form that is sending this response. Use `FormApp.openByUrl` to get a reference of the Google Form.